# Multiple files in one MemoryStream?

Tags: c#, memorystream

Is it possible to save a list of files into one MemoryStream and save the files later back to the disc?

Comment: Can you be more specific?  At the moment your question doesn't make that much sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well yeah, there are a few ways of doing this but one would be to do something like this:

```
class MyFile
{
    public byte[] Data;
    public string FileName;
}

List<MyFile> files = GetFiles();
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    // Serialise
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(stream, files);

    // Deserailise
    stream.Position = 0;
    List<MyFile> deserialisedFiles = (List<MyFile>)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
    SaveFiles(deserialisedFiles);
}
```

Where you should be able to figure out roughly the implementation of `SaveFiles` and `GetFiles`.  I'm not entirely clear why you want to do this though.